# Modular arihmetics in AtMega

Tags: c, atmega

I am developing a device firmware with some cryptographic functions. I use CodeVisionAvr IDE and AtMega324 microcontroller. I need to implement an modular exponentiation function like this:

```
unsigned long XpowYmodN(unsigned long x, unsigned long y, unsigned long N)
```

But there is no data types bigger than `long` types in CodeVisionAvr! Is is any way to implement this function without operating numbers more than 2^32-1(`long`)?

Comment: [Arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)

Comment: Assuming `(x^y)%N` and `x` small (it depends but is mostly the case in crypt.) you don't need anything bigger than what fits in an  `signed long`. Remember that  `(x*y) %N = ((x%N) * (y%N)) %N`  and `(x^y)%N = ((x^(y/2))%N)^2%N`, so any `x < LONG_MAX /2` will do. But do yourself a favour: the available keylength with native integers is way too small, use big integers. E.g.: LibTomMath works well in memory restricted environments (you can strip it down to what you need if you compile it yourself)